# Are $6C4$ and $6C2$ the same, and are they topologically equivalent?

Tags: combinatorics

$6C4$ and $6C2$ result in the same value, but they seem to explicitly refer to two different situtations, eg. arranging four `1`-s in `001111`, and, on the other hand, two `0`-s in `001111`. Are $6C4$ and $6C2$ the same?

I guess an analogous problem is the equations

```
2+1=3

3+0=3

4-1=3
```

have different expressions on their left sides, yet result in the same value on their right.

This problem naturally begs the question: are the two expressions topologically equivalent?

[image]

Comment: The binomial coefficients $\binom 6 4 = 15 $ and $\binom 6 2  = 15$ are equal. What kind of “topological equivalence” are you thinking of?

Comment: On one hand you don't know a simple result like ${n \choose k}={n \choose n-k}$, but on the other you know a concept of topological equivalence (that no one else seems to know, though)?

Comment: How is arranging $4$ $1$'s in $001111$ any different from arranging $2$ $0$'s in $001111$? You're still arranging $6$ objects of $2$ different types. And what do you know of topology that leads you to ask this question?

Comment: Awesome! Just from the definition of the binomial coefficient ${n}\choose{k}$ as the number of $k$-subsets of an $n$-set, we can know, that `nCk` refers to the cardinality of the set of $k$ subsets. I thought that `nCk` told something about the results of choosing the elements, for example {'AB', 'AC, 'BC'}, {'A','B','C}, which can be also represented as vertices and edges of a triangle, or nodes and twigs of a tree diagram. Or, simply, as three parallel lines, and three parallel lines are topological equivalent with three parallel twigs of the diagram, but not with the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't understand what you mean by "topologically equivalent", here's one way to understand why

$$\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$$

Consider a batch of $6$ students. And say we want to pick $2$ of them for a committee.

So how many ways are there to choose the $2$ students. Well, $\binom{6}{2}$. Obviously.

But we can achieve the same result by doing the following. We can choose $6 - 2 = 4$ students who *won't* be in the committee. That would be $\binom{6}{4}$ ways.

In both cases we are doing the same thing. Separating the $10$ students into two groups. Those we want in the committee and those we don't.

So,

$$\binom{6}{2} = \binom{6}{4}$$

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you Haris! Your answer does help, I now understand `nCk` as asking "*how many ways* can we choose k elements from n". For example, we could ask "how many ways can we separate rocks". I still struggle to understand how 3C1 and 3C2 differ, as the different number of $k$ elements results in different combinations. Also, saying "take two pebbles" seems to mean something slightly  different to "leave one pebble".